# images zoom (high number) on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css

I need to position a lot of image on a specific points of a background image (like 250 images) on a single HTML page.
After that User can click on zones of that map and see it zoomed (in and out - 2 level) based on the click itself.
is there some jquery plugins capable of that or is it possile to zoom the container div and the contained images will be zoomed? is there some css trick?
I'm a bit confusing because not able to find a direct solution using the search and manuals...
Thanks,
a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a jQuery plugin like lightBox. See if you like one of these:

- jQuery UI dialog box: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
- Fanxybos: http://fancybox.net/
- shadowbox.js: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html
- Colorbox: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: I used `fanxybos` all the time

Comment: no, sorry. I'm not looking at that effect. I need to have all the div zone is zoomed and not only one image. Think about the googlemaps zooms .

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt a plugin like [Impress](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored). It allows a large field of items that you can zoom in on, one by one.